# Nancyfx Views not found when debugging ASP.NET Core 1.0 application

Tags: nancy, asp.net-core-1.0

Am having problems resolving Nancyfx views with Asp.net Core 1.0 in debug mode. This is because folders like `wwwroot` are not output in the `bin` folder. I've googled but have not found anyways of sending folders to `bin/Debug`. However when I published and run the app the views are resolved fine. This is because the `project.json` I can configure for folders to be outputted. I know I can customize the `ViewLocations` but if I do so for it to work in `debug` then it will not work when `published`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have couple of options here:

1. Setup the `ContentRoot`. The following code uses the project directory as the location for views.

   ```
       public class Program
       {
           public static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                   .UseKestrel()
                   .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                   .UseIISIntegration()
                   .UseStartup<Startup>()
                   .Build();

               host.Run();
           }
       }
   ```
2. You can use the `copyToOutput` node in `project.json` for this purpose.

   Example:

   ```
   "buildOptions": {
     "copyToOutput": {
       "include": [
         "Areas",
         "Views",
         "wwwroot",
         "config.json",
         "web.config"
       ]
     }
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much. The first option I was already using but not working. Option `2` does the job.

Comment: Now with the default template for ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Core) in VS2017 there is no project.json again by default. Settings have migrated back to the project file. I was able to just set the file properties on the View to Content | Copy if newer.